# Syntax Error or Access Violation comes up when logging into the program

Tags: sql, sql-server

our program connects to a db and when you sign into the program, it's throwing this error: "Syntax error or access violation" along with "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'CADDB.dbo.AuditTrail'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails"

I've tried Microsoft's Fix to Use ANSI Nulls, Padding and Warnings in the ODBC connections, but it still occurs.

Can someone point me where to look? I believe it's corrupt data in the db... but not 100% sure. I will attach the error that gets logged with that message if you need me to.

Comment: To find out where the issue is you have to debug and recreate the error manually. Assuming you have access to the 'CADDB.dbo.AuditTrail' table then manually write an INSERT statement from SQL Management Studio, if it succeeds then the issues is with the UI which is not capturing all required input fields. If the database insert itself fails then you have to figure out how to fix that part.

Comment: Correct- our developers have a debugger for this program (just found out) but the issue was a corrupt db. We got a more recent backup and it doesn't error out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The exception showed you the root cause that your app is trying to insert NULL value into column ID, a column not allowing NULL. If this is caused by your application's bug and you also want to insert a NULL value into ID column. Then you may change the table to allow NULL for column ID or use a special value representing NULL (not recommended) for the insertion.

Otherwise, it is more likely to be your application's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the column from `CADDB.dbo.AuditTrail` `allow nulls`,check your table schema for that, or you could try insert into the column `ISNULL(value,'NULL')`, which is the **string null** not actual `NULL`.

`ANSI_NULL` query option only be took into effect when doing the value comparison. which is `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL` when it is set to `ON` or using `=/!=/<>` when set to `OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ISNULL()` function. Example `ISNULL(column Name, '')`

I'm not sure if you're using `T-SQL` script in your code to access the table, or you can alter the column to allow nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody! The issue was the db was corrupt. I got a working backup of the same db and it works fine without any errors.